# Spring Batch with support of Scheduler

Tags: spring, scheduler, spring-batch

**Scenario:** The system needs to check the Product table in the database DAILY to check every product's expiration date. The system needs to get a list of products with expiration dates matching the current date. Then, removes these products in the database.

Things to consider:
 - Runs a single query to retrieve products that has matching expiration date.
 - Remove these products in the database.
 - We are talking about thousands of products here.

**QUESTION:** Is there a need for me to create a Spring Batch Job supported with Scheduler for this or just a Scheduled Job to do this efficiently?

Because in Scheduled Job, I can just schedule the checking and removing daily. And its done. At the same time, I can also do it using Spring Batch with Scheduler. But, what do you think is the more efficient way?

Comment: can't understand your question. what's your problem indeed? scheduling or not scheduling? (beside my opinion, that spring-batch for a single job is pretty much overkill. look at the spring Scheduled-Annotation or Quartz.)

Comment: I am asking for a more efficient way to code this. Do I need to implement Spring Batch in removing the products in my database or is Scheduler in Spring enough already?

Answer (score 0):

i think spring batch would be a wise decision, if you need to restart your job with more steps inside. otherwise, if it's really just one job, you could solve that restart functionality anyway manually...

all those spring-batch configuration aren't that heavy in your applicationcontext, but you need to create tables for the according repository. (perhaps you gotta stage those tables as well..)

**Spring Batch:** 
if you need restart-functionality

**Common Scheduling:** Easy and fast, ain't need that much knowledge about the framework

Comment: Even though there would be a lot of rows in the database to be affected? What if I am about to check thousands and thousands of products in my table? And it happened that there was an interruption during the process, can Common Scheduling handle that?

Comment: @EarlKlugh Spring-Batch internally handles database access with jdbc as well - it's no godlike tool which speed-up your database actions insanely. You can configure spring-batch to handle your input in chunks, but thats all in my opinion (you can do that as well, for example split up your inserts in many transactions). To your second question: if theres a pure technical problem (like a power blackout,  which forces your jvm to shutdown, spring-batch won't be able to handle that as well) - usual catchable exceptions for example might cause your transaction to roleback.